# How to add multiple addListenerOnButton in android studio

Tags: android

This is Activity_main.xml for an android app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sanzuup150"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sanzuuq150"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sanzuur150"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm very new to android developing so I dont know how to create addListenerOnButton for imageButton2 and imageButton3 by different url. Please help me......

Ths is MainActivity.java

```
package com.android.screation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent browserIntent =
           new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,         Uri.parse("http://www.sanzuu.blogspot.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }

    });

}

}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve the way you implemented listener is right, do you want single listener to class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listener should be put on each imageButton. 
Each imageButton is an item in the xml then should be (let us say) linked to in the java using the id. Therefore the ids in the same xml should be unique. Always link the element to its reference in xml before using or else the code will null pointer exception.

```
package com.android.screation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton imageButton;
ImageButton imageButton2;
ImageButton imageButton3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); // refer to the id in the xml
imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
imageButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

//add the listener to the specific button
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is button 1",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent browserIntent =
           new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,         Uri.parse("http://www.sanzuu.blogspot.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }

    });
imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
//what imageButton2 is supposed to do
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is button 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

       // what imageButton3 is supposed to do here
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is button 3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });

}

}
```

If you need any more help please feel free to ask.

Comment: very fast and helpful answer for beginners. It worked for me.

Comment: how to add toast effect on every image button for the same code?

Comment: Please check the edited answer. If you have any question do not hesitate to ask me. Happy coding